# Sending data to different report suite

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I have a website which is running on web and mobile. We have 2 different report suite for web and app so that data can be analyzed granularly.

Now, we have certain pages which are common across. For example there is an article page which is when viewed in web sends data to web report suite.
Problem is when we open same article in app in mobile view, the analytics data is sent to web report suite.

When article opens in web the url is “abc.com” and when open through mobile app the url is “abc.com?view=mobile.

Is there any way v can dissect data on basis of url and send data to different report suite.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can. Some pseudo-code for you:

```
if (URL meets criteria for mobile app)
    {s.account=mobilereportsuite;}
else {s.account=desktopreportsuite;}
```

More information on s.account can be found here: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/s_account.html

Additionally, if you have an implementation in DTM, the process is slightly different. Under code configuration, select the 'custom' radio button, then check 'set report suites using custom code below'. More information on this process can be found here: https://webanalyticsfordevelopers.com/2016/08/02/dynamic-report-suite-id-with-dtm/